# url rewriting and subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

It possible to rewrite url of the form
http://website.com/page.php to http://page.website.com, and when I enter an url such as 
http://page.website.com, it will treat it as http://website.com/page.php?

When I am on the page, can the address bar continue showing http://page.website.com ?  How can I achieve all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your default directory page to include "page.php". In that case, it would be served if you requested the directory.
Add the following to the .htaccess's DirectoryIndex line

```
DirectoryIndex page.php ...
```

Also refer to [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess6.shtml).

EDIT:

Whichever pages you want the server to search for within the directory, when you try to request the folder, you specify them in order in the DirectoryIndex part of your .htaccess.

e.g.

If you have an index.html and a page.php, in the same `www.site.com/example/example2` folder, apache serves the index.html by default. But you can override this behavior using the .htaccess file.

If you want the server to serve the page.php when you request for `www.site.com/example/example2`, put it in your .htaccess as `DirectoryIndex page.php`.

Then, that will ensure that it serves the php page.
Hope I was clear! Read [this](http://www.twsc.biz/twsc_hosting_htaccess.php)!

Comment: im sorry but i dont understand the logic of this syntax even after reading the link you gave me. I added the code to my htaccess file nothing happened when i entered http://page.website.com, i want the http://page.website.com to stay on the adress bar when entered, but treat it as http://website.com/page.php. i dont understand why there is an index.html in that syntax, very confusing stuff >_<

Comment: im sorry this is so confusing. Do you want me to add "DirectoryIndex page.php" in the htaccess file in the pub folder? That confuses me becouse it would make more sense if it was ../page.php going one level up. But if u ment adding the line "DirectoryIndex page.php" in the htaccess file in the root folder along with the page.php then i am totally lost. Does this mean every empty folder will show page.php? normally i would feel studpid when not understanding something explained twice, but now im too lost to do even that ^^ Again sorry for beeing difficult, its not my intention..

Comment: .htaccess files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file, containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a particular document directory, and the directives **apply to that directory, and all subdirectories thereof.**

Comment: so if you want **only** the **/example/example2** directory to serve page.php by default, you would change the .htaccess, in **/example/example2** --> [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html.)

Comment: 1) i have an empty folder in website.com/pub/ except for the .htaccess file which only contains one line of code which is "DirectoryIndex page.php", the page.php is not inside the pub folder, but its in a folder one level up in the root folder. in the root folder i have another .htacess file which contains no line of code about directory index. When i now enter this address : website.com/pub/ i get nothing up except for "Index of /pub"

Comment: Does the pub directory contain page.php? Where is the page.php located?

Comment: no! why would i want that? I think you believe i asked for this: "if  dont want to call the default file in a folder index.php but page.php how can the folder treat page.php as the default file to load". This is not what im asking.

Comment: That would fix your concern of your browser displaying just the directory and everything. Why would you want to use mod_rewrite for this?